# How to dynamically change a header text on Material UI dialogue with an if statement?

Tags: reactjs, function, if-statement, react-hooks

[image]

**Modal.js**

```
import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent, DialogActions } from "@material-ui/core";

const Modal = (props) => {
const { title } = props;

<Dialog>
   <DialogTitle>
      {title} // <- Where the dialog header text is passed into.
   </DialogTitle>
   <DialogContent/>
   <DialogActions/>
</Dialog>

}
```

**Main.js**
I've create an if statement to change the header title between `Add Information` and `Edit Information`.

```
import Modal from "../Modal";

<Modal
   title={() => {
       if (materialValues.id === 0) { // <- materialValue.id = 0 if adding new information.
           return "Add Information";
       } else {
           return "Edit Information";
       }
   }}
/>
```

I feel that this code should work, but it comes out empty without any error statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a function that is never called to return a value. Use a ternary operator to pass one or the other title value. The ternary expression will be immediately executed and the result passed in the `title` prop to the `Modal` component.

```
<Modal
  title={materialValues.id === 0 ? "Add Material" : "Edit Material"}
/>
```

Comment: Of course! For some reason I have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer.